# PHP Printing Text Problem

Tags: php

i want to print directly to a printer using PHP, but i have a problem..

It showed up in the printer's queue, but it didn't print at all..
the status change from print to delete in a split second

Here's the code i'm using :

```
if($ph = printer_open('EPSON TM-U210B Partial cut')){
     printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "raw");
     printer_write($ph, 'testing');
     printer_close($ph);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to [start a document](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.printer-start-doc.php) and [create a page in it](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.printer-start-page.php) to write on. The result should look like this:

```
<?php
$ph= printer_open('EPSON TM-U210B Partial cut');
printer_start_doc($ph, "My Test-Document");
printer_start_page($ph);

// your code here
printer_write($ph, 'test 123 ...');

printer_end_page($ph);
printer_end_doc($ph);
printer_close($ph);
?>
```